# Dart 2.13 performance changes doens't work

Tags: flutter, dart

After reading the article on the new version of Dart 2.13, it says that the performance and size of the original apk file have been improved ...

I installed the latest versions of Dart and Flutter and ran the counter starter project, compiled and I got 5.9 mb release version.
Based on the article in version Dart 2.12, size = 5.9 mb, but with version Dart 2.13, the size should shrink by 35% = 3.7 mb
But it doesn't work

Help me get 3.5 mb of the release file instead of 5.9 mb

[Article link Dart 2.13 performance changes](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-13-c6d547b57067)

Comment: Do I understand you right, you're assuming every app will automatically be 35% smaller? I'm afraid that's not what the article says (nor intends to say)...

Comment: I do not expect all this magic to work automatically.

Based on the article, I decided to check if this is so and tried the described example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article says:

> Take as an example the Flutter Gallery app. On Android the release APK is 112.4 MB with debug information, and 106.7 MB without it (a 5% overall reduction). This APK contains a lot of assets. Looking just at the code metadata inside the APK, it was reduced from 5.7MB in Dart 2.12 and only 3.7MB in Dart 2.13 (a 35% reduction).

The 35% number comes from the Flutter Gallery app (not the example counter app) when built with the `--split-debug-info` flag.

The 35% also only refers to *code metadata* (i.e. the bit that is split off when using `--split-debug-info`). The overall APK sees only a 5% difference.